# Rendering multiple chart.js charts in one page when scroll to the section

Tags: javascript, html, animation, charts, chart.js

I have four chart.js charts on one page rendering fine. Each chart is sitting on a separate div with heavy content. But they load all at once, so when you scroll to the bottom of the section, you don't see the charts' animation anymore.
Is there a way to load each chart when the users scroll close to that section?

```js
 // setup
    const data = {
        labels: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '% of Respondents',
                data: [55, 51, 46, 36],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.2)'
                ]
            }]
    };

    const data2 = {
        labels: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '% of Respondents',
                data: [55, 51, 46, 36],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.2)'
                ]
            }]
    };

    // config for myChart
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }  
            },
            indexAxis: 'y'
        }
    };

    // render myChart
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );

    // config for myChart2
    const config2 = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data2,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            },
            indexAxis: 'y'
        }
    };

    // render myChart2
    const myChart2 = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart2'),
        config2
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
   <div class="blankDiv" style="height: 700px;width: 100%;">
        Scroll Down to See the chart
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 70em;">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="blankDiv" style="height: 700px;width: 100%;">
        Scroll Down to See the chart
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 70em;">
        <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant two charts, not four. I started four, but reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deferred plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-deferred.netlify.app/guide/) for this:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDeferred);

const data = {
  labels: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
  datasets: [{
    label: '% of Respondents',
    data: [55, 51, 46, 36],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.8)',
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.6)',
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.4)',
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.2)'
    ]
  }]
};

const data2 = {
  labels: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
  datasets: [{
    label: '% of Respondents',
    data: [55, 51, 46, 36],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.8)',
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.6)',
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.4)',
      'rgba(79, 38, 131, 0.2)'
    ]
  }]
};

// config for myChart
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
};

// render myChart
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);

// config for myChart2
const config2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data2,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
};

// render myChart2
const myChart2 = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart2'),
  config2
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-deferred@2.0.0 "></script>
<div class="blankDiv" style="height: 700px;width: 100%;">
  Scroll Down to See the chart
</div>
<div style="max-width: 70em;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="blankDiv" style="height: 700px;width: 100%;">
  Scroll Down to See the chart
</div>
<div style="max-width: 70em;">
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG! You're my lifesaver! Thank you so much!!!